# hibernate 4 - sessionFactory.addPackage - configuration file analogue?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, configuration, hibernate-4.x

I think in Hibernate 3 there was a property key `hibernate.packagesToScan`
which one could set at the session factory level in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.
Is this key changed in Hibernate 4 and if so, what is its corresponding key?

I am using version 4.3.8 final.

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate properties you need:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
```

In persistence.xml you need:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Comment: Can I just go without using persistence.xml and JPA respectively? See also these 2 related questions, you'll get a better idea what I'm trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107513/hiberate-4-3-entity-class-instances-not-returned-in-list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097847/hibernate-4-3-x-load-all-entity-annotated-classes

Comment: Try with the hibernate property first. It should be ok even if you don't have persistence.xml

Comment: You mean I put that in hibernate.cfg.xml ? I am fine even with calling `addPackage` programmatically, my main problem is that Hibernate doesn't really recognize my persistent classes even in that case, I cannot create a simple `Criteria` and do `list` on it (I get empty list back?!). +1 for trying to help.

Comment: Btw, based on some research I did, I think it turned out `hibernate.packagesToScan` is a Spring-specific thing. I am not using Spring in this project, so it does not help.

Comment: It should go in hibernate.cfg.xml. If you get an empty list, it's because you have no data. If you supply a Class that not a Hibernate entity, you get an exception, not an empty list.

Comment: I have data because if I do `session.createSQLQuery` and not `session.createCriteria`, and I query the same table (using the 1st approach), it works fine and it returns about 100 records.

Comment: Make sure the entity table matches the one you used in the SQL query.

Comment: Well, I did, it's called `Category`, the underlying RDBMS is MySQL. Thanks anyway, I'll keep looking for a solution, I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing here.

Comment: Also, I have SQL logging enabled, note that when I use `Criteria`, hibernate doesn't generate any SQL at all to the RDBMS. I have no idea why. And when I use `createSQLQuery` I can see "select * from..." generated.

Comment: That's weird indeed. Usually you get an Exception, when the entity is not resolved. I haven't heard of not having the SQL generated at all.