# hibernate 4.3.x - load all entity annotated classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x

In a project which I work on I don't use Spring, I use Hibernate only. I don't want to use hbm.xml files for entity mappings/descriptions/etc. I want to use annotations only.

How do I tell Hibernate to load all `Entity/Table` annotated classes from certain package(s)?

I searched on the web but I have no luck. Also I don't find information about the latest Hibernate version (mostly outdated articles/posts/etc.).

**Edit 1:**

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping

The hibernate doc page says this:

> Object/relational mappings can be defined in three approaches:
>   1) using Java 5 annotations (via the Java Persistence 2 annotations)
>   2) using JPA 2 XML deployment descriptors (described in chapter XXX)
>   3) using the Hibernate legacy XML files approach known as hbm.xml

So that's it, I just want to use 1) with the 
SessionFactory/Session Hibernate API.

**Edit 2:**

*Even though my questions was marked as duplicate, it's not, because I don't want to use JPA (and the implied descriptors) but just approach 1) from those listed above.*

Comment: @hwellmann What if I don't want to have persistence.xml but only hibernate.cfg.xml? Do I need to have both? I just wanted hibernate.cfg.xml with the behavior of Hibernate scanning the annotated entity classes. Isn't that possible?!

Comment: @VladMihalcea What if I don't want to have persistence.xml but only hibernate.cfg.xml? Do I need to have both? I just wanted hibernate.cfg.xml with the behavior of Hibernate scanning the annotated entity classes. Isn't that possible?!

Comment: In other words I thought with those annotations in the entity classes, I can just avoid using .hbm.xml mapping files and still use the SessionFactory & Session APIs provided by Hibernate, and have these APIs know about my entity classes. Any ideas how to most easily achieve that?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping

Comment: Anyway, my question is in no way duplicate to the question pointed out above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, this is not possible in Hibernate 4.3.x and was never possible it seems.

See also this question/answer (even though this post is old, it's quite valid):
[Add Annotated Class in Hibernate by adding all classes in some package. JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122792/add-annotated-class-in-hibernate-by-adding-all-classes-in-some-package-java)

1) After I did some research on this, it seems it's a common misconception that `Configuration.addPackage` allows us to load all entity classes from a given package. It's not true. I found it the hard way by looking in the hibernate sources and only then I found the above SO question/answer which confirmed it. In fact I am not quite sure what `addPackage` does, but it doesn't seem very useful for my case.

2) Seems one thing we can do is to call `Configuration.addAnnotatedClass` for each of our own annotated entity classes e.g. by hard-coding those classes at compile time. Or ... alternatively by using [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) or [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) we can find all (i.e. our own) entity classes from a given package dynamically at runtime, loop through them, and still call `Configuration.addAnnotatedClass`. The only problem with Reflections is that it comes with quite a few dependencies of its own. So we have to add 9 new JARs for this simple thing (what a pain) if we decide to use Reflections. With Guava it's somewhat easier, we can just call
`ClassPath.from
(
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
).
getTopLevelClasses(pckg)`.

*If anyone has a better approach - feel free to provide it.

I will accept the best answer, not necessarily my answer.*

Comment: I just went through this headache myself.  Starting with what seemed to be the obvious "addPackage".  However, I did end up still using addPackage after adding in all the classes with the code above.  It reads the package level meta data (pacakge-info.java) which I put some annotations in for custom types.