# hiberate 4.3 - entity class instances not returned in list

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I am using Hibernate 4.3.8 without Spring. I am using Hibernate's session API. I have one entity class `Category` which I have annotated properly with `@Entity`, `@Table`, `@Id`, `@Column` and so on. I don't use .hbm.xml descriptor files, I just want to use the annotations in my domain/entity java source/class files.

1) OK, I create my hibernate `SessionFactory` in this way:

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();          
        // configuration.addClass(Category.class);
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = 
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        configuration.addPackage("com.test.db.domain");
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

2) Then when I try this:

`session.createCriteria(Category.class).list();`

I just get an empty list back (I was expecting to get all categories that are in the DB table). The `Category` class is in the com.test.db.domain package.

**What could be the reason for this? I am stuck for almost a day on this.**

3) Note that if I use `session.createSQLQuery` I can connect to my DB and get all categories.

4) Also note that I don't want to use Hibernate's EntityManager API, JPA, and the XML descriptor(s) related to JPA.

Comment: can you not use a test in-memory db for testing with RESOURCE_LOCAL? Then you can simply do `createQuery().getResultList()` and get all the results.

Comment: @ha9u63ar Who said I use in-memory DB? I use MySQL. Also, I have nowhere RESOURCE_LOCAL specified. Can I do what I want without persistence.xml or it's not possible? Also, `Criteria` has no method `getResultList`. I am trying to run a `Criteria`, not a `Query`

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion, it was simply a question. Also, have you added any records before calling session.createCritera(Category.class).list()? JBoss docs has an example here - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: @ha9u63ar Oh, I see. OK, that's not what I'm trying to do. I am trying not to use persistence.xml, only the Session API and annotations instead of hbm.xml mapping files.

Comment: @ha9u63ar I have records, read item 3) from my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the following: calling `configuration.addPackage` does not do what I initially expected it to do. See also:

[hibernate 4.3.x - load all entity annotated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097847/hibernate-4-3-x-load-all-entity-annotated-classes)

Instead of calling `addPackage` what one should do is to call `configuration.addAnnotatedClass` for each class from his own entity/domain classes.